# Die Position von zwei Pronomen

Tags: word-order

Welche Variante ist richtig?

> Herr Leopold versprach, dass es mir Frau Arina nicht antun würde.

> Herr Leopold versprach, dass mir Frau Arina es nicht antun würde.

> Herr Leopold versprach, dass es Frau Arina mir nicht antun würde.

> Herr Leopold versprach, dass Frau Arina es mir nicht antun würde.

Comment: Was und mit welcher Begründung denkst du selbst, was richtig ist?

Comment: Gibt es einen Kontext? Ist das eine Übungsaufgabe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default word order has known information first, new information later. It's a bit tricky to construct clauses by that because a bit of “information” may be more than one sentence item, and the verbal bracket often requires a certain order.

But fortunately it usually boils down to topic (in main clauses) — V2 verb (in main clauses) — subject — pronoun accusative object — dative object — adverbials (but direction) — noun accusative object — directional adverbial / prepositional object — remainder of predicate verbs.

Your examples differ in that order of subject and objects.

> …, dass es mir **Frau Arina** nicht antun würde.

This one marks the subject new information and emphasizes it.

> …, dass mir **Frau Arina es** nicht antun würde.

This one marks both the subject and especially the pronoun accusative object new information and thus, emphasize them.

> …, dass es **Frau Arina mir** nicht antun würde.

This one marks both the subject and especially the dative object new information and thus, emphasize them.

> …, dass Frau Arina es mir nicht antun würde.

This is the default order.

Comment: Hinsichtlich 'Normalität'/'Sprachüblichkeit'/'Akzeptabilitätsgrad' wäre zu überlegen, inwieweit das Pronomen 'es' hier wie überhaupt nicht in sehr vielen Fällen durch 'das' oder 'dies'  ersetzt würde, frei gesprochen wohl auf jeden Fall. Für mich am normalsten und bezogen auf Hervorhebung am neutralsten wäre _Herr Leopold versprach, dass Frau Arina mir das nicht antun würde._ Interessanterweise ist hier die sonst bei zwei Pronomen zu erwartende Reihenfolge 1 Akk. 2 Dat. vertauscht. Grammatiken nennen dieses _das_ 'Demonstrativpronomen', für mich ist es betontes 'Personal'pronomen.

Comment: *Das* steht später als *es*, weil etwas, das definitit ist, tendenziell eher neue Information darstellt. Und sei es nur dadurch, dass die Definitheit neu eingeführt wurde.

Comment: Ist denn das 'es' nicht definit?